# Angular dependencies not loading using Browserify and Debowerify

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to use Browserify + Debowerify to load Angular.js but I get a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in browser console after I run gulp serve at run the app. When I use npm to install Angular everything works.

In my package.json I have:

```
{
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "debowerify"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {,
    "browserify": "^5.10.0",
    "browserify-ngannotate": "^0.1.0",
    "debowerify": "^0.8.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^0.1.1"
    ...
  }
}
```

I installed Angular with with

`bower install angular`

And inside my main.js I add:

`require("angular");`

In my gulpfile.js I have:

```
...
gulp.task('browserify', ['clean'], function() {
  browserify('./app/scripts/main.js')
    .transform(debowerify)
    .transform(ngAnnotate)
    .transform(uglifyify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe($.streamify($.rename({suffix: '.min'})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts'));
});
...
```

Here's a pastebin of my bundled js file http://pastebin.com/Uar8VkVMI'm

What is it that I'm doing wrong? Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: `uglifyify` ? Is it right or should it be simply `uglify` ?

Comment: You said what error you get, but not when: during the gulp build, during page load, when interacting with the app... ?

Comment: yep https://github.com/hughsk/uglifyify

Comment: And the error is in the console after I run gulp serve and access the app in browser